# Generate python scripts from GUI by duplicating existing python script

Tags: python, code-generation

I am trying to build a platform where I already have a GUI and a Python script (*e.g., process.py*) with socket programming codes in it. I want to generate more Python scripts from the GUI in such a way that it will duplicate *process.py*.

In other words, I want to click from the GUI that will duplicate *process.py* and create a new *.py* file.

How can I build such an automated script generation?

Comment: In even other words, you want to copy a file?

Comment: What GUI env? Tkinter? Without code the best you're likely going to get is "copy the contents of the file to a new file and edit the contents as needed" -- which is very simple in Python

Comment: Yes, Tkinter. It is all going to be part of a platform that can generate new python scripts.

Comment: Please show your code for your GUI in Tkinter and you will probably get this resolved in a few minutes. All it is, is a button click and execution of copying a file and editing contents as needed...this is without context of your real issue, more-or-less what @Kelsey shows below

Answer (score 2):

You can call:

```
import shutil
shutil.copyfile(source_path, dest_path)
```

Whenever the GUI is clicked on, you trigger the python script to do the duplication, pass in the source path of the file you want to duplicate and the destination path of what you want it to be named.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-duplicate-file-of-an-existing-file-using-python/

Comment: Please add your imports...not all beginners in python will understand how to execute the code without full imports shown. Ex: `import shutil`